# How to call init function of Dropzone after every time I click a button using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade, dropzone.js

I have a list of similar `<div>` elements created with a `for` loop. For each of these `<div>` elements, I have a button to edit information. Every time this edit button is clicked, a pop-up opens containing a Dropzone box (using the [Dropzone library](https://www.dropzone.dev/)). Now, to load images related to each `<div>`, I change the input value associated with the image ID using jQuery.

However, I need to read the changed ID from the input and use it in the Dropzone's `init` function. The issue is that the Dropzone was created before changing the input value, and during the initial page load, it has an empty value. I want to re-run the Dropzone `init` function with the same configuration as the previous one after each click on the edit button.

I will now post the code snippets for reference.

**HTML File:**

```
@foreach($steps as $step)
    <div class="row card p-3 mb-3 d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-12 row justify-content-between align-self-center mb-2">
            
            <div class="col-6 p-0">

                <button type="button" class="btn update_step" title="update"
                        data-toggle="modal" data-target="#update_step_modal"
                        step_number="{{$step->number}}"
                        route="{{route('panel.contents.clusters.steps.update', [$content->id, 
                        $cluster->id, $step->id])}}">

                    <span class="mdi mdi-18px mdi-square-edit-outline"></span>
                </button>
              </div>
         </div>

         <div class="col-12 row justify-content-center align-self-center mb-2">
             <p class="col-12 step_description_p">{{$step->description}}</p>

             <div class="col-6 justify-content-center pt-4">
                 <input class="step_cover_id" value="{{$step->cover_id}}" hidden>
                 <img src="{{$step->cover_image}}">
              </div>

         </div>
    </div>      
@endforeach
```

**Modal HTML File:**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="update_step_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- 
      labelledby="update_step_modal" aria-hidden="true" data-keyboard="false" data- 
      backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="col-12 row justify-content-center align-self-center">
                    <form action="" method="POST" id="update_step_form">
                        @method('PATCH')
                        @csrf

                        <textarea name="description" id="update_step_description"></textarea>
                        <input name="cover_id" id="update_step_cover_id" hidden>
                        <input name="video_id" id="update_step_video_id" hidden>

                    </form>
                </div>

                <div class="col-12 row justify-content-center align-self-center mb-2">

                    <div class="col-6" id="update_step_cover_div">
                        <form action="{{url('panel/upload')}}" method="POST" 
                               class="dropzone" id="update_step_cover_form">
                            @csrf
                            <input name="type" value="step_cover" hidden />
                            <input name="content_id" value="{{$content->id}}" hidden />
                            <input name="cluster_id" value="{{$cluster->id}}" hidden />
                            <div class="dz-message" data-dz-message>
                                <span class="m-dropzone__msg-desc">some messages</span>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <button type="button" class="btn" id="step_update_button">
                        <span class="ladda-label">update</span>
                        <span class="ladda-spinner"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript File:**

```
$('.update_step').on('click', function () {
   let step_number = $(this).attr('step_number')
   let route = $(this).attr('route')

   $('#edited_step_number').text(step_number)
   $('#update_step_form').attr('action', route)

   let parent = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
   let description = parent.find('.step_description_p').text();
   let cover_id = parent.find('.step_cover_id').val();
   let video_id = parent.find('.step_video_id').val();

   $('#update_step_description').val(description).change();
   $('#update_step_cover_id').val(cover_id).change();
   $('#update_step_video_id').val(video_id).change();
});

Dropzone.options.updateStepCoverForm = {
    paramName: "file", 
    uploadMultiple: false,
    acceptedFiles: "image/*,",
    maxFiles: 1,
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-Token': $('input[name="_token"]').val(),
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    },
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    init: function() {
        let coverDropzone = this;
        let id = $('#update_step_cover_id').val()

        if(id !== ''){
            $.ajax({
                url: '/panel/fetch_file/' + id,
                type: 'get',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                    var mockFile = {name: response.data.file_name, size: response.data.size};

                    coverDropzone.emit("addedfile", mockFile);
                    coverDropzone.emit("thumbnail", mockFile, response.data.file_path);
                    coverDropzone.emit("complete", mockFile);
                    coverDropzone.options.maxFiles = 0;
                }
            });
        }

        this.on("removedfile", file => {
            let id = $('#update_step_cover_id').val()
            remove_file_function(id, "update_cover")
        });
    },
    accept: function(file, done) {
        done();
    },
    success: function (file, response) {
        $('#update_step_cover_id').val(response.data.id).change();
    },
    error: function (file, response) {
        error_function(file, response)
    }
};
```

Comment: Why not use a class name instead of an ID so you can have multiples on the same page?

Comment: Because every time this page is loaded, an API is called for each image (in some stages, video) and this increases the page load.  This is while with this work, only one or two APE calls may be made. @ChrisBarr

Comment: Maybe reinitialize Dropzone on button click?

Comment: How can I do that? @AztecCodes

Comment: @NegarJavadzadeh When you hit the `update_step` button, once you've configured the input values, you remove the previous Dropzone (if it's there), and then proceed to construct a fresh one. This ensures that the revised input value is picked up by the init function of the new Dropzone.

Comment: Could you please explain how can I remove existing dropzone? @AztecCodes

Comment: @NegarJavadzadeh I posted an answer. I hope it helps you.